# PIL image displays weird black image

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

**I've been trying to add image to the another image, but it gives this weird black overlay, how can I fix it?**
[test.png]

[image: 1]

```
from PIL import Image

image = Image.open("inventory.png")
image2 = Image.open("item.png")
image2 = image2.resize((80, 80))
image.paste(image2, (x,y))
image.save('test.png')
```

Comment: What were you *expecting* the result to look like?  We have no way of knowing...  If `item.png` has proper transparency information, then you just need to use a drawing command that actually makes use of it - either add a `mask=image2` parameter to `.paste()`, or use `.alpha_composite()` instead of `.paste()`.

Comment: Yes, I was missing the mask=image2, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's likely that your `item.png` has a transparent background, so the original image background is showing through.  If you want the square to have a white background, you need to draw a solid white square before pasting the image.

Or, if it is a bilevel black-and-white image, there may be confusion over which is black and which is white.  If that's the case, `ImageOps.invert` will fix it.